# TimeZone.getDefault() Attribute value must be constant error

Tags: java, json, spring, timezone

I'm trying to set the time zone to system default.

I have a `String` variable in `BatchDateUtils.java` class:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_TIMEZONE = TimeZone.getDefault().toString();
```

What I try to achieve is:

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", timezone = BatchDateUtils.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE)
private Date reportDateFrom;
```

I get:

```
Attribute value must be constant
```

In general I understand what the error is, but how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: @AndyTurner That's exactly what I'm avoiding right now. I don't want to hardcode the timezone. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Yes, define the conversion manually rather than with must-be-fully-constants annotations (like there will still be an annotation, but referencing a class to perform the conversion, and that class will be made by you and determine the time zone to apply when it is run)

Comment: @kumesana could you give me some more details, I don't really understand

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone` and the other old data and time classes. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZoneId.systmDefault().toString()` and other functionality from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And as Andy Turner said in the answer, relying on the default time zone is fragile because it may not be constant.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a value in an annotation, you have to define a constant value, for example `"Europe/London"`.

Something which depends on JVM configuration is not a constant; but more generally, anything using the result of a method is not a constant.

Additionally, it is rarely a good idea to depend upon the default time zone, because it can be changed at runtime, can easily be misconfigured etc.